# Confused about protecting against XSS and which tools to use

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, xss

VS2013, MVC, VB

I'm asking this question now because much time has passed since most of the posts that I read about XSS protection.

In the spirit of SO, my technical question is if someone can confirm that Microsoft's HtmlAgilityPack does not really do what AntiXSS does.  I've read posts where people suggested that AntiXSS has problems, so they used htmlAgilityPack, but then the posts, including on SO, that state clearly they are not the same tool.  That AntiXSS is what one would use for XSS protection.

If someone could clarify that I'd appreciate it.

A second, and not intended to be asking an opinion question per se, is to ask if the problems previously claimed against AntiXSS are by and large solved and is that the right tool to use for XSS protection when using MVC.

My intent is to use a whitelist approach for XSS protection.

Comment: there was, imo, a pretty good CodProject article about this yesterday. Maybe you will find it useful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/877794/Preventing-XSS-in-ASP-NET-Made-Easy

Comment: That was a great article-thx.  Still digesting and will have some more questions as there were a few points not quite clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed the guidance from [this post](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/222/request-validation-in-asp-net-web-pages) as a basis for coding a whitelist filter using the html agility pack.  The link shows a function used in a web pages approach, but the basic algorithm works fine coded in the controller of an MVC project to sanitize input from an RTF/WSIWYG editor (CKEditor)